# Loading JSON data into snowpipe

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

we have below Valid JSON data which resides in S3 and we are trying load this data  into snowflake table by snowpipe .

"Vendor": {
"string": "ABC"
},
"vmAddresses": [{
"Address": {
"string": "addr1"
},
"Category": {
"string": "order"
}
]

```
SELECT $1:Vendor.string::varchar,
$1:vmAddresses[0].Address.string,
object_keys($1:vmAddresses[0]),
object_pick($1:vmAddresses[0],'Address', 'Category')
FROM @S3://20210310194308.json
```

with OBJECT_KEYS we are able to get the keys but unable to get the corresponding value of it . the below format is what we are trying to get

{
"Address":  "addr1",
"Category": "order"
}

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't just using "$1:vmAddresses[0]" give you the value?

Comment: added additional query based on your comment

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to validate your sample text trough parse_json and an online json formatter, both of them complained about invalid JSON. I corrected it, and run **your** SQL:

```
with json_data as (
select parse_json( '{ "Vendor": {"string": "ABC" }, "vmAddresses": [ { "Address": { "string": "addr1" }, "Category": { "string": "order" } } ] }' ) j)
select j:Vendor.string,
j:vmAddresses[0].Address.string,
object_keys(j:vmAddresses[0]),
object_pick(j:vmAddresses[0],'Address', 'Category')
from json_data;
```

And it worked as expected:

- j:vmAddresses[0].Address.string <-- returns *"addr1"*
- object_keys(j:vmAddresses[0]) <-- returns *[ "Address", "Category" ]*
- j:vmAddresses[0] or object_pick(j:vmAddresses[0],'Address', 'Category') <-- returns
  *{"Address": { "string": "addr1" }, "Category": { "string": "order" } }*

Which value are you trying to parse? Everything seems working.

Additional answers based on comment:

You can use object_construct to build the JSON after reading the values with the vmAddresses[0].Address.string notation:

```
with json_data as (
select parse_json( '{ "Vendor": {"string": "ABC" }, "vmAddresses": [ { "Address": { "string": "addr1" }, "Category": { "string": "order" } } ] }' ) j)
select OBJECT_CONSTRUCT( 'Address', j:vmAddresses[0].Address.string, 'Category', j:vmAddresses[0].Category.string )
from json_data;
```

Comment: Hi Gokan thanks for your answer and we need output as below format                                                                                            {
  "Address":  "addr1",
  "Category": "order"
}                                                                                                                                                     Thanks in advance